# Confusion regarding Laplace transform calculation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, laplace-transform, terminology

I am trying to learn about Laplace transform and especially about ROC and i found out on [this weblink.](http://jntuhsd.in/uploads/programmes/Module15_LT_13.01_.2017_.PDF)

I have also attached a snapshot of this link and highlighted where it is being said that although the signals are differing, their Laplace Transforms are identical

My MATLAB code

```
clc
clear
close all
syms s t a
x1=exp(-a*t)*heaviside(t)
x2=-exp(-a*t).*heaviside(-t)
X1=laplace(x1,s)
X2=laplace(x2,s)
```

When i run above script i get X2=0, but as per above mentioned web link , i should have got $1/(s+a)$

Why i am getting different values of X1 and X2?

[image]

I have also attached snapshot of above weblink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Matlab implementation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.laplace.html) of the Laplace transform computes the *uni-lateral* (one-sided) Laplace transform:

[image: Screenshot of Laplace page on Mathworks website]

Since $x_2(t)$ is zero for $t\gt0$, the result of the uni-lateral Laplace transform must be zero.